# Convert DB2 EBCDIC column to Ascii in a SQL Statement

Tags: sql, db2

I know I can do the conversion very easily using C# or any other number of programming languages, however, I want to know if I can do the conversion of a column that has EBCDIC encoded text so that the result of the query is in a readable string such as ascii encoded.

Ultimately, I will import the data into SQL Server and I know SSIS can do it, but before I do that, I want to exhaust any paths that are not SQL language.

For example a little know combination of built in functions available in DB2 SQL or SQL-Server 2008

Here is an example of data

Data as stored in DB2: 0xC6C3C3C1E3C5D9D7C9D3D360F8F840

Text: FCCATERPILL-88

The C# conversion is so easy so I included it here:

```
 System.Text.Encoding ei = Encoding.GetEncoding(37);
            textBox1.Text = ei.GetString(allBytes.ToArray())
```

I'm not an AS400 admin so I'm not sure what to do with what is being suggested in the comments.

Comment: If your application-codepage (on Windows) is correctly set then the Db2 client should automatically convert from EBCDIC to ASCII for you when you retrieve a result-set from Db2 (assuming Db2 is running on Z/OS).

Comment: You also need the CCSID of the columns set correctly in Db2, the should be CCSID 37.  If they are CCSID 65535, that tells Db2 they are binary data and it won't convert it automatically.  Depending on your platform and driver, they may be a setting to force conversion of CCSID 65535.